# Visual studio 2013 for web not responding for aspx files

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 express for web is working fine but when I am trying to open aspx files editor is not at all responding when I open other files it is working fine, I am not able to see even the cursor in editor. When I open design tab I can see cursor and its working fine.

Comment: Have you tried [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) yet?

Comment: No I have not tried @Steven V

Comment: Visual studio 2013 has crashed while running in safe mode @Steven

Comment: I am getting same error even in safe mode

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine at this point. If it's still doing it in safe mode then it isn't a plugin or configuration issue. I'd probably uninstall and reinstall, or see if the issue continues on a different user profile.